# could not convert ‘0l’ from ‘long int’ to ‘MemoryManager’

Tags: c++, class, function, null, type-conversion

```
MemoryManager openMemory() {
  if (...) {
    return memory_manager_instance;
  }
  else 
    return NULL;
}
```

`MemoryManager` is the name of a user defined C++ class. The function definition above gives me the error in the title.

Basically I don't want to return an instance when the condition does not hold. Such definition of function is valid and what I usually do in Java, but it seems not working in C++. What should I do to tackle this?

Comment: Java has only pointers, that's why you can return NULL object. In C++ your code requires conversion constructor in MemoryManager, which doesn't exist or is explicit. You probably meant to return a pointer not a value. It's also possible you might need to throw an exception or return a default initialized object -- there is no way to tell from your question.

Comment: Read mkb's answer so that you understand what is happening. Then, returning NULL in this particular instance is probably not what you want anyway - you should probably throw an exception (as @Gene) says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have your function return a `MemoryManager *` (perhaps using one of the several smart pointer classes available in the C++ library or in boost). If `MemoryManager` is the name of a class, then this function as written returns a copy of `memory_manager_instance`. This is different from Java, where a variable of type `MemoryManager` would be a reference to an object.

EDIT: Further, it looks like you are trying to implement a singleton. You'd want to make the default constructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator for `MemoryManager` private or protected. The first two are in Java as well, but not the last!